# angular gmail login with selected host domain

Tags: angular6, google-signin

I am using angular-6-social-login in my angular app for google login. It's working fine. But I want to specify hosted domain in this. So only two specified domain users will be able to login on it. Currently this module does not support this functionality. Is there any way to overwrite it.

existing code:

```
`GoogleLoginProvider.prototype.initialize = function () {
    var _this = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        _this.loadScript(_this.loginProviderObj, function () {
            gapi.load('auth2', function () {
                _this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: _this.clientId,
                    scope: 'email'
                });
                _this.auth2.then(function () {
                    if (_this.auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
                        resolve(_this.drawUser());
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
   };`
```

my requriment:

```
    `GoogleLoginProvider.prototype.initialize = function () {
     var _this = this;
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        _this.loadScript(_this.loginProviderObj, function () {
            gapi.load('auth2', function () {
                _this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: _this.clientId,
                    scope: 'email',
                    hosted_domain:'abc.com'
                });
                _this.auth2.then(function () {
                    if (_this.auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
                        resolve(_this.drawUser());
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
   };`
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 6 social login package doesn't support for the custom configuration to specify the hosted domain.
Instead, you can change the angular-6-social-login.umd.js file in node_modules.

Change the GoogleLoginProvider.prototype.initialize function and add the below details in gapi.auth2.init function
 1. scope should be 'email'
 2. fetch_basic_profile: false 
 3. hosted_domain: your domain.

```
gapi.load('auth2', function () {
                _this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: _this.clientId,
                    scope: 'email',
                    fetch_basic_profile: false,
                    hosted_domain: <your-domain> ,
                });
                _this.auth2.then(function () {
                    if (_this.auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
                        resolve(_this.drawUser());
                    }
                });
            });
```

This will work for the specified domain.

The second option You can use [angularx-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login) provides you to configure the hosted domain in the configuration option.